# Nodejs axios get taking long time than postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, node-modules

I am developing a node js project. In the project, am using axios.get to call a third party API. The API call from postman takes 500ms. But from my nodejs axios.get takes around 1.2s. Is it an expected behaviour?

This is the nodejs snippet am using

```js
const axios = require('axios');
let response = await axios.get(
       baseURL + BasePath + `-${reqParams.Number}`,
        {
          headers: {
            'X-Correlation-Id': 'correlationid',
            'X-Client-Id': clientId,
            'X-Client-Secret': clientSecret
          },
         timeout: 20000
        }
      )
```

Comment: How are you measuring the time? Are you also making a request from client for that data?

Comment: One things that is wrong here is that [`axios.get()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axiosgeturl-config) takes only two arguments, not three.

Comment: @Phil : yes it takes 1.2 s.

Comment: @charlietfl: I am just checking using console.time and console.timEnd in nodejs api call.
Something like

```console.time(Start),
axios.get()// api Call,
console.timeEnd(Start)
```

Comment: @jfriend00: yes you are right. I updated it.

Comment: @user846445 code goes in your question, not in the comments

Comment: Difference can be related to other processes running while you make this request and other requests load on your server also

Comment: @charlietfl: I don't think so . I am just making only one request and checking.

Comment: It's only a difference on 700 ms. If you are not developing anything mission critical, this shouldn't even be concerning. And, there can be many reasons for perceived delays so, you might want to employ more mechanisms for getting a more accurate measurement before jumping to any conclusion.